# How to show border on TextInputLayout in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout

In my application I want use TextInputLayout and I want set border for this view.
Such as this image : [Image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7459254/69254180-ad4a7b80-0b6a-11ea-980e-baa41075eb29.png)

**I write below codes :**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/loginFrag_phoneInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15mdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15mdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15mdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15mdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15mdp"
    android:hint="@string/insertYourPhoneNumber"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginFrag_title">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/signInFrag_phoneEdt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10mdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10mdp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_10mdp"
        app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/ic_phone" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**I added this line :**

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

But when update material design library to **v1.3** not show me any border!

```
'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

But in **v1.2** or **v1.1** show me border and not any problem!

Why not show border in **v1.3** ?
How can I fix it?

Comment: How about wrapping it inside a view with background and giving it some margin? For example, <FrameLayout background=#000000 > <YOURVIEW margin=1dp background=#FFFFFF/> </FrameLayout>

Comment: Basically you want a phone icon should be displayed in edit box, that's why  you are using     app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/ic_phone"    along with transparent background to make icon visible, am I correct ?

Comment: @NRUSINGHAMOHARANA , yes but how can i fix it?

Comment: use app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_action_phone"  in TextInputLayout and remove both android:background="@android:color/transparent" and app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/ic_phone" from TextInputEditText. I updated my answer.

Comment: in theme.xml you have to also set the material theme http://prntscr.com/115fzwe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **remove** the background `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` in the `TextInputEditText`.

Also don't use `app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/...."` in the `TextInputEditText` but use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
        app:endIconMode="custom"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank my friend, I fix my problem. but my language is RTL when click on EditText show hint on the line!! please see this image : https://i.ibb.co/XxDqNz4/39.png how can i fix it? thanks

Comment: @Miss.Ellen It happens because you're setting the edit text android:gravity to right it's getting inverted since it's in RTL, so you don't need to specify any gravity.

Comment: yeeeeees. thanks my friend for your helps. it's ok

Answer (score 1):

I am also using v 1.3.0 and getting correct border using below code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginFrag_phoneInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_action_phone"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/signInFrag_phoneEdt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="11"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, but again not show any border

Comment: Can you check my answer now. I am using v 1.3.0 and getting correct border.

Comment: Yes my friend, in your code show border. but not show border in my codes? my codes and your codes are not any different ! why ?

Comment: Could you try with your code by removing app:boxStrokeColor="@color/teal_200" ? I hope this line makes different.

Comment: Please see my post, I updated my codes with you codes. please see above post. thanks

Comment: android:background="@android:color/transparent" in TextInputEditText causes the issue. I removed it and also removed drawableRight from TextInputLayout. To show phone icon I put app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_action_phone" to TextInputLayout.